# Pythonic way to add numeric columns of the individual dataframes of a groupby object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series data that I group and I want to sum the numerical columns of all the groups together.

**Note**: This is not an aggregation of column of individual groups, but a sum of corresponding cells of all the dataframes in the group object.

Since it's a time series data, a few columns in essence remain the same in a dataframe like `Region` and `Region_Code` and `Time` itself remains same across the dataframes.

My pseudo code is -

1. Groupby `Region_Code`
2. Select only the numerical columns of grouped object
3. Make Region list
4. Call the dataframe in the group object by iterating over the region list and sum
5. Make the other columns like `Region`, `Region_Code` and `Time`

But the problem is that when I add the called dataframe with an empty dataframe, everything becomes empty/null so eventually I have nothing.

```py
import pandas as pd

countries = ['United States','United States','United States','United States','United States', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'China', 'China', 'China', 'China', 'China']
code = ['US', 'US','US','US','US','CAN','CAN','CAN','CAN','CAN', 'CHN','CHN','CHN','CHN','CHN']
time = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
temp = [2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5, 3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5, 4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5]
pressure = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2]
speed = [20,21,22,23,24, 10,11,12,13,14, 30,31,32,33,34]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Region': countries, 'Time': time, 'Region_Code': code, 'Temperature': temp, 'Pressure': pressure, 'Speed': speed})

countries_grouped = df.groupby('Region_Code')[list(df.columns)[3:]]

country_list = ['US', 'CAN', 'CHN']

temp = pd.DataFrame()
for country in country_list:
    temp += countries_grouped.get_group(country) ## <--- Fails

temp

# Had the above worked, the rest of the columns can be made as follows
temp['Region'] = 'All'
temp['Time'] = df['Time']
temp['Region_Code'] = 'ALL'
```

It does not look pandorable. What's the best way to do this?

**Expected Output**:

```
    Region  Time    Region_Code     Temperature     Pressure    Speed
0   All      1          ALL              9.3            3.3       60
1   All      2          ALL              9.6            3.3       63
2   All      3          ALL              9.9            3.3       66
3   All      4          ALL              10.2           3.3       69
4   All      5          ALL              10.5           3.3       72
```

Comment: How looks expected output DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael Added expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need aggregate `sum` - all non numeric columns are exclude by default, so you can add them by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by original columns with repalce missing values by `ALL`:

```
print (df.groupby('Time', as_index=False).sum())
   Time  Temperature  Pressure  Speed
0     1          9.3       3.3     60
1     2          9.6       3.3     63
2     3          9.9       3.3     66
3     4         10.2       3.3     69
4     5         10.5       3.3     72

df = df.groupby('Time', as_index=False).sum().reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value='ALL')
print (df)
  Region  Time Region_Code  Temperature  Pressure  Speed
0    ALL     1         ALL          9.3       3.3     60
1    ALL     2         ALL          9.6       3.3     63
2    ALL     3         ALL          9.9       3.3     66
3    ALL     4         ALL         10.2       3.3     69
4    ALL     5         ALL         10.5       3.3     72
```

EDIT: For custom replace missing values use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with dictionary - column name with value for replace:

```
d = {'Region':'GLOBAL','Region_Code':'ALL'}
df1 = df.groupby('Time', as_index=False).sum().reindex(df.columns, axis=1).fillna(d)
print (df1)
   Region  Time Region_Code  Temperature  Pressure  Speed
0  GLOBAL     1         ALL          9.3       3.3     60
1  GLOBAL     2         ALL          9.6       3.3     63
2  GLOBAL     3         ALL          9.9       3.3     66
3  GLOBAL     4         ALL         10.2       3.3     69
4  GLOBAL     5         ALL         10.5       3.3     72
```

Comment: It's so very close. Actually there are 2 columns `Region` and `Region_Code` and they actually take different values NOT `ALL`. I probably should have used better example. Let's say for `Region` i want `GLOBAL` and Region_Code I want `ALL`, in that case what do I do?